# Best approach to Insert Composite relation in DAL

Tags: c#, database, insert, data-access-layer, relational

I'm creating a custom DAL to persists and get data from database. For single entities there is no problem. But I need an implementation for related entities. This is a composite relation.

For example, I have a Contact class

```
public class Contact
{
    public ContactId {get;set;}
    public Name {get;set;}
}
```

And classess for specific contact types:

```
public class Customer : Contact
{
    public CustomerNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Should I create a CustomerDAL class with an Insert(Customer customer) method that inserts into Contact and Customer tables, or should I create 2 DALs, CustomerDAL and ContactDAL that inserts each entity separately?

Whats the best approach/pattern to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think inheritance in the answer here. What you're doing is making Customer a child class of Contact which gives you access to the properties but "flattens" the design and limits your DAL to only allow a single contact on a customer.

I'd be tempted to expose the Contact through a property

```
public class Customer
{
    public ... your usual customer properties go here
    public Contact contact {get; set;}
}
```

If you're likely to have many contacts on a customer which I'd suggest you would have, then:

```
public class Customer
{
    public ... your usual customer properties go here
    public List<Contact> contact {get; set;}
}
```

Are you hand rolling your own DAL form scratch rather than using an ORM tool such as Entity Framework to save time? If you have foreign keys in your database, it can also detect these and create this properties for you. But, of course, you might be using a different type of data store, in which case, ignore me on this part of the answer. Remember, even if you use EF to create the POCO , you're not obliged to use it for DB queries if you don't want to. 
However, if you still need the speed of ADO.NET, you can used EF to execute your own SQL queries or stored procs without using LINQ and can still benefit from things like connection handling and retrying queries.

Comment: For reasons beyond my control I cannot use a real ORM, so I am forced to create a custom DAL

Comment: A Customer is a Contact, thats why I'm inherit, I mean, when I create a Customer, I should insert into Customer and Contact tables, Contact stores the information like Name, email and Customer is a table extension, used to store specific information for Customer, like CustomerNumber for example. There are another tables like Supplier or Student that inherit from Contact for example.

Comment: I'd need to see more of your design, but it sounds like there a more fundamental issue with what you're trying to do.
So, to answer you original question, I'd keep separate DAL and Repository queries for Contact and Customer as they are both separate tables in the DB, But, of course, there's nothing to stop your customer DAL/respository calling the other. I assume you're following the repository pattern too.